# Unix Scripting if statement correction

Tags: unix, if-statement, scripting

im trying to check if my script ran correctly if not, to echo a message, however when i use this if statement, it produces an error on line '9' (`if [ $? -eq 0 ]`) Saying that a ' is missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
if ["$name" = ""]
then
 echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "
        read name
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "Incorrect Input"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ["$name" = ""]
```

is wrong because you must have a space between the `[` and the expression (and before the `]` as well).

There's nothing obviously wrong with the syntax of

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

but it's always dubious to check exit codes with arithmetic, since that's what `if` does directly. If your script is as you show it above, the second `if` statement should always be true. The fact that the previous `if` statement's expression was false doesn't matter, because the `if` statement [yields zero](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_07) if no condition tested true. For example:

```
$ if false; then echo hi; fi; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Well the first if statement runs fine. its the second one that keeps producing errors asking me to put a ' somewhere.

Comment: I think you're thinking into it too deep. Its a small assignment for my starter scripting class. It just echo a message if there was an incorrect input. thats it.

Comment: @AndrewBarsoom how does it know there's an incorrect input?

Comment: Because it searches through a phonebook list, if the user does not input a name within the phonebook, it throws an error, i want to catch that error and echo back saying its an invalid input.

Comment: Any Thought? ;x im stuck

Comment: @Andrew Did you leave out the statement that searches through the phonebook? Your comment suggets that the second if is looking to the result of the phonebook-search.